# PHP foreach loop select records from database in order

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
foreach($items as $row) {
   $data = array(
           name = $row->name,
           item = "SELECT section from articles WHERE user_id = 2 LIMIT 1"
    );
}
```

now my articles table looks like this:

```
id     user_id  section
=============================
1      2        XYZTRWE
2      2        GWERSTI
3      2        QRTPSLG
```

The problem is that always very first record from articles gets picked up.

What I would like for example, if I have 2 records in `$items` array, `$data['item']` values should be `XYZTRWE` and `GWERSTI`, but I always end up with `XYZTRWE` for all values.

Comment: You're overwriting the value in `$data` each time though your syntax is wrong anyway. How exactly do you want it ordered? Alphabetical descending?

Comment: You need to show more. The query you have will return all three rows, but I don't really get what you're trying to do with the loop. I also think that your syntax is incorrect, and if this is your actual code, I'm surprised you get any result at all.

Comment: @aynber order should be descending.

Comment: I have updated query, to limit 1 record.

Comment: Show your database query. You can use `ORDER BY column_name DESC` to have mysql reorder the results for you. Though, again, if you're getting `XYZTRWE` for all values, you're overwriting something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the loop in this instance if you want to view all the records with user_id = 2 in descending order. The SQL statement should be

```
"SELECT section FROM articles WHERE user_id = 2 ORDER BY section DESC"
```